# Как сделать так, чтобы бот пересылал сообщение определенному человеку?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем привет, пока что только-только начинаю заниматься телеграмм-ботами, поэтому, вопросы могут быть слишком простыми, извините.
Проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы какое-то определенное сообщение пересылалось какому-то определенному пользователю. Я попытался сделать так, чтобы сообщение, в котором было слово 'анкета' пересылалось, но мне не хватает знаний. Помогите, кто-нибудь)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message(msg):
    if msg.text == "анкета" and input():
        bot.forward_message(
            chat_id=айди, 
            from_chat_id=msg.chat.id,
            message_id=msg.message_id            )
```

Comment: А что за and input() ? И у вас после слова анкета пробел

Comment: Про пробел знаю, а and input() - это моё непонимание того, как сделать правильно))

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, можно было просто сделать так. Оставлю здесь, вдруг кому-то понадобится

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def message(message):
    bot.send_message(айди, message.text)
```

Comment: Можно и так, только это не пересылка, а отправка от имени бота.

Comment: А можете сказать, как сделать именно пересылку?

Comment: Методом forward, вы использовали его в вашем вопросе.